# Change polygon fillColor with javascript (google maps)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to change Google Maps polygon fillColor on click.
Here is my code => https://jsfiddle.net/nw6j52f6/

Аnd here is the problem part of code.
The function that should change design of polygons:

```
function polyopt(i) {
setOptions({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000', strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3, fillColor: '#FF0000', fillOpacity: 0.35
});
}
```

but console return this error:

```
map-array.html:56 Uncaught ReferenceError: setOptions is not defined
at polyopt (map-array.html:56)
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (map-array.html:69)
```

i'm using Google Maps API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolygonOptions

but i don't understand why the console show this error.

Comment: Where do you call the `polyopt` function, and what are you passing to it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nw6j52f6/

Here is the entire code. I call polyopt function at 74 line



<input type="button" onclick="polyopt()" value="green">

Comment: `onclick="polyopt()"` - you don't pass any argument to that function which could be used to work out which polygon you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

if you polygon is `i` you must use `i.setOptions`

```
function polyopt(i) {
   i.setOptions({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000', strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3, fillColor: '#FF0000', fillOpacity: 0.35
});
```

Comment: Same Error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setOptions' of undefined
    at polyopt (map-array.html:51)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (map-array.html:63)

Comment: seems that have undefined instead of a valid polygon .. you myst pass a valid polygon in var (i) .. check you code where you create polygon and invoke funcion

Comment: i have 5 polygons in array

var layers = [];

  layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url: 'http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml',
          map: gmap});
  layers[2] = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url: 'http://***.com/testovoo.kml',
          map: null});

Comment: You have 5 **KmlLayers**, not **polygons**. KmlLayers don't have options to set strokeColor or strokeWeight, read: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#KmlLayerOptions